# Opencv Camera calibration generate very distorted images

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, fisheye

I am trying to calibrate a fish eye lens using opencv.

After capturing some images and using sample code that comes with opencv. I am getting these images:

[image]

This image is undistorted as follow:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: opencv uses a pinhole-camera model for calibration. it probably just don't work with a real fish-eye lens

Comment: @berak: Thanks. So how can I undistorted a fisheye lens with opencv?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem before. The default (pin-hole) model didn't work well with very wide-angle lens. You should try [fisheye model](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your camera closer to the pattern, so that the pattern can cover more than half of the image.

Or, you need to print a larger size pattern (such as A0-size if possible), which will give you a very accurate result.